# image in div bigger than window size, hide vertical scroll bars?

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have a mouse move functionality to scroll a 3544 x 4092 image in a div, filling the whole screen.

I got rid of horisontal bars using:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

But nothing else works thus far for the vertical bars. Any ideas would be helpful.

This is the CSS for the div containing the image (its parent is the body):

```
#zoompage{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120%;  
    z-index: 300;
    left: -10%;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you can prevent vertical scroll bars with `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow-y: hidden;`.

Comment: I figured -- so it's hard to tell why it's not working in your particular case without more info or a link.

Comment: Only other thing to it- I add the image to the div like this `$("#zoompage").html('<img src="path"/>').show();` and this goes over all content untill hiding it on click

Comment: What part of this doesn't apply to your case? http://jsfiddle.net/MRSallee/Fw7SP/

Comment: I see now, my div was set more than 100% hence having bars. No scrollbars now but also not scrolling now.halfway there, thanks